# How to get Keras accuracy for each step in an epoch like in Tensorflow?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

Like in tensorflow I get accuracy for each step -

```
Step 1, Minibatch Loss= 68458.3359, Training Accuracy= 0.800
Step 10, Minibatch Loss= 451470.3125, Training Accuracy= 0.200
Step 20, Minibatch Loss= 582661.1875, Training Accuracy= 0.200
Step 30, Minibatch Loss= 186046.3125, Training Accuracy= 0.400
Step 1, Minibatch Loss= 161546.6250, Training Accuracy= 0.600
Step 10, Minibatch Loss= 286965.3125, Training Accuracy= 0.400
Step 20, Minibatch Loss= 205545.7500, Training Accuracy= 0.600
Step 30, Minibatch Loss= 202164.6562, Training Accuracy= 0.800
Step 1, Minibatch Loss= 214717.7969, Training Accuracy= 0.600
Step 10, Minibatch Loss= 108088.7344, Training Accuracy= 0.800
Step 20, Minibatch Loss= 80130.6016, Training Accuracy= 0.800
Step 30, Minibatch Loss= 28674.1875, Training Accuracy= 0.800
Step 1, Minibatch Loss= 78675.6641, Training Accuracy= 0.400
Step 10, Minibatch Loss= 168231.2812, Training Accuracy= 0.600
Step 20, Minibatch Loss= 77828.1406, Training Accuracy= 0.600
Step 30, Minibatch Loss= 56584.9609, Training Accuracy= 0.800
Step 1, Minibatch Loss= 29474.0898, Training Accuracy= 0.600
Step 10, Minibatch Loss= 79742.9531, Training Accuracy= 0.800
Step 20, Minibatch Loss= 0.0000, Training Accuracy= 1.000
Step 30, Minibatch Loss= 6736.4688, Training Accuracy= 0.800
```

But in keras I get accuracy for each epoch -

```
156/156 [==============================] - 6s 39ms/step - loss: 13.0185 - acc: 0.1923 
Epoch 2/10
156/156 [==============================] - 3s 18ms/step - loss: 12.9151 - acc: 0.1987
Epoch 3/10
156/156 [==============================] - 3s 18ms/step - loss: 13.1218 - acc: 0.1859
Epoch 4/10
156/156 [==============================] - 3s 18ms/step - loss: 12.9151 - acc: 0.1987
Epoch 5/10
156/156 [==============================] - 3s 18ms/step - loss: 13.1218 - acc: 0.1859
Epoch 6/10
156/156 [==============================] - 3s 18ms/step - loss: 12.9151 - acc: 0.1987
Epoch 7/10
156/156 [==============================] - 3s 18ms/step - loss: 12.8118 - acc: 0.2051
Epoch 8/10
156/156 [==============================] - 3s 18ms/step - loss: 12.8118 - acc: 0.2051
Epoch 9/10
156/156 [==============================] - 3s 18ms/step - loss: 12.8118 - acc: 0.2051
Epoch 10/10
156/156 [==============================] - 3s 18ms/step - loss: 12.9151 - acc: 0.1987
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom `CallBack`:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback

class NBatchLogger(Callback):
    "A Logger that log average performance per `display` steps."

    def __init__(self, display):
        self.step = 0
        self.display = display
        self.metric_cache = {}

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        self.step += 1
        for k in self.params['metrics']:
            if k in logs:
                self.metric_cache[k] = self.metric_cache.get(k, 0) + logs[k]
        if self.step % self.display == 0:
            metrics_log = ''
            for (k, v) in self.metric_cache.items():
                val = v / self.display
                if abs(val) > 1e-3:
                    metrics_log += ' - %s: %.4f' % (k, val)
                else:
                    metrics_log += ' - %s: %.4e' % (k, val)
            print(f'step: {self.step}/{self.params['steps']} ... {metrics_log}')       
            self.metric_cache.clear()
```

The inspiration for the code is [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2850).

Comment: Ya i have set the verbose to 0 as the progress bar was showing up everytime while printing accuray of each step.